# How to fix Kuali startup error Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.url'?

Tags: java, kuali

How to fix Kuali startup error Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.url'?

On startup I am getting an error which keeps Kuali from starting.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'riceDataSourceXAPool' defined in class path resource [org/kuali/rice/core/RiceDataSourceSpringBeans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.url'
```

I expect Kuali to start with no errors.

Comment: Kuali is a FOSS product that runs on Tomcat, Jetty, etc.  How is it off topic compared to Confluence or XWiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it can't find your rice-config.xml